# Topic subscription - at least once processing

Tags: java, messaging, hazelcast

I have a topic based event publisher which I would like to replay the previous 20,000 events on subscription. The publisher doesn't support this functionality and I don't want to run another service like Kafka.

I have an application that will subscribe to the topic and publish the events to a `ReliableTopic` provided by Hazelcast. If I've understood correctly, I can configure the backing ringbuffer to provide the functionality I'm after.

There are multiple instances of this application for redundancy. How can I prevent all the instances are subscribing to the event publisher and publishing to the `ReliableTopic`; ending up with `n` x event on the `ReliableTopic` (where `n` is the number of instances)?

This is fairly easy to handle when there are no failures (eventid mod instance number)...its the failure scenarios that I am stuck on - what happens when instance `x` dies.

I am looking for "at least once" (and hopefully once most of the time) style processing - my application can technically support duplicates.

Comment: For instance by using a distributed ILock you can make only one instance of the application eligible for publishing. If that instance dies, assuming it's using a Hazelcast client for Hazelcast operations, all locks hold by that will be released and another instance can pick it up.

Otherwise I don't understand the question much since you'll be able to detect duplicate publishes since there'll be instance info in the message (eventid mod instance number) as I understood.

Comment: What about the events that get published between the lock being "released" and then "locked" by the next instance of the application...these events get lost, so I don't have "at least once" processing.

Comment: If you want to eliminate duplicate publishes, you can block the publisher to have the lock before it can publish. Otherwise you can allow duplicate publishes and handle the duplicates at listener side

Comment: I think you are missing something here....what I am publishing to the ReliableTopic is coming from another Topic based system...its this system that I can't loose messages from...the question is how do i handle multiple subscribers to this other topic based system but only process the message by one instance *most of the time*